# mongoose query to update a document in a model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
jsn = {
"data":[
 "Id":"123",
 "qnty":[{"qId":"3","qItem":123},]
]
}
```

hi, i want to update document's using mongoose in nodejs, but unable to do so, what i want is to update the "qitem" of qnty array of object and insert similar other objects in update, my approach is below.

```
var doc = await model.findOne({"data.Id":x});

//if i have qnty object already present i want to update its value
doc.toObject().data[0].qnty[0].qItem = 100;

//i want to push many object this is just example
doc.toObject().data[0].qnty.push({"qId":"4","qItem":124});

doc.save();
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
model.update({"data.Id":x},{"data.qnty":doc.data[0]})
```

in place of `doc.save()` i think that will do the trick